# SonarQube installation failing to start service

Tags: sonarqube

I'm installing sonarqube on Windows Server 2012.

I have followed the following steps:

1. Downloaded sonarqube4.4 and extracted to C:\Sonarqube
2. Downloaded Java JDK 1.7.0_60 and jre 1.7.0_67 as well as jre7
3. Installed Windows SDK 7 and .NET Framework 4
4. Navigated to C:\sonar\bin\windows x86-64 and ran StartSonar.bat as an administrator, this ran ok with no output and Ihad to hot ctrl- Z to break
5. I then ran \windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat as an administrator and I am seeing the sonarQube services was launched, but failed to start.

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It could help to have a look at C:\Sonarqube\logs\sonar.log

Answer (score 9):

I believe you first ran `\windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat` successfully and then `StartSonar.bat` unsuccessfully (the inverse order of what you describe).

You probably have [this problem]: http://qualilogy.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/09/Sonar_ServiceLaunchError2.jpg

> Windows could not start the Sonar service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

In that case, the solution is to change the user/rights to launch the Sonar service: https://qualilogy.com/en/migrate-sonarqube-tomcat-to-windows-service/

Go to the Services window, find the Sonar service, and open the Properties windows to change the user it logs on as to one with sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a new folder named “Temp” in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\`

Answer (score 0):

The Log-File will show only

> --> Wrapper Started as Service
>
> Cleaning or creating >temp directory C:\Program Files (x86)\SonarQube\sonarqube\temp
>
> <-- Wrapper Stopped
>
> **The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.**

After a long search, I came up to this site http://zen-and-art-of-programming.blogspot.de/2013/03/installing-and-running-sonar-source.html.

Solution:

1. Navigate to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\` and create the directory `Temp`

2: Set the user rights to full access

3: Run the `StartNTService.bat`