# SonarQube install

Tags: installation, sonarqube

I'm using oracle db. When I start SonarQube I always get this error.

```
A:\SOFTWARE\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>startsonar
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2015.06.29 18:32:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless
=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSIni
tiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=A:\SOFTWARE\sonarqube\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchSe
rver C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process7899461072017026572properties
jvm 1    | 2015.06.29 18:32:07 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
jvm 1    | 2015.06.29 18:32:07 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=tr
ue -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=A:\SOFTWARE\sonarqube\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;A:\SOFTWARE\sonarqube\extensions\jdbc-driver\o
racle\ojdbc6.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\p\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process8819840513490201682properties
jvm 1    | 2015.06.29 18:32:08 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2015.06.29 18:32:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

A:\SOFTWARE\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>
```

Image
[image: https://tracker.czech-server.com/dox/7/b779a8d68c044318248d79846c4c06806b99ccc0.png]

I followed this tutorial:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Here is log github.com/p4tooo/log/blob/master/sonar.log

Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific and use a link that works not only for you.

Comment: here is public screenshot https://tracker.czech-server.com/dox/7/b779a8d68c044318248d79846c4c06806b99ccc0.png I used this tutorial http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Comment: Please provide logs/sonar.log.

Comment: Here is log https://github.com/p4tooo/log/blob/master/sonar.log

Answer (score 5):

From the log you provided, it appears that a program on your computer is already using port 9000 on host "192.0.0.1".

By default, SQ services bind to all IPs available on the computer (here, there's probably only one: "192.0.0.1"). Port 9000 is used by the Web Server of the SQ instance you're trying to start. Since it is not available, the web server fails to start and the SQ instance is stopped.

The program already using port 9000 might be an SQ instance you launched and forgot to shutdown, or another program.

In the former case, start the Task manager and kill the SQ instance.

In the later case, there is tools out there to find out which program is using port 9000. Google for it, find the culprit and either turn it off or kill it with the task manager.

If port 9000 can not be freed to be used by the SQ instance, an alternative is to change the "sonar.web.port" property value in the "sonar.properties" file of the instance to a free port. When necessary and possible, you can even bind the WebServer to another IP by changing the "sonar.web.host" property.

Comment: Port 9000 is not used, but I tryed change port in sonar.web.port. Still same  error.

Comment: If it is not the port, then the problem is coming from the fact the WebServer is trying to bind to host "192.0.0.1".Usually it's "0.0.0.0" or "localhost". Did you change anything?

Comment: I didn't change host. All settings are default. Here is properties file https://github.com/p4tooo/log/blob/master/sonar.properties

Comment: Well, the root problem is still that the port 9000 on host "192.0.0.1" is not available. If it is not used by a program (or a service) then it might be a firewall issue.

Comment: @PatrikSensel I just noticed that your "sonar.properties" file isn't exactly the default "sonar.properties": by default, sonar.web.port and sonar.web.host are commented out.

Comment: I uncommented it, because i tried use diferent ports ... Here is list of used port https://github.com/p4tooo/log/blob/master/port.txt there is not :9000. I switched off windows firewall. Do you use teamviewer?? Thanks

Comment: In the logs you provided, the error comes to attempting to bind to host "192.0.0.1". I see only "192.0.0.2" is the port listing you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but did you first install the Sonar service?
Have you verified that there is no Windows user's rights problem?

I believed this is the case from your log but well ...
Regards.

Comment: I followed this tut http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing;jsessionid=446C4B4E5D30DE988F16D18C95A68C3C#Installing-installingWebServerInstallingtheWebServer there is nothing about Sonar service ... I started up cmd as administrator

Comment: If you are under Windows, you have to install Sonar as a service before to start it. Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750108/sonar-qube-installation-on-windows-server-2012/25783011#25783011 can help