# SonarQube service was launched but failed to start?

Tags: sonarqube

I am currently trying to install SonarQube. When following the instructions on their page, I came to the instruction to run the **InstallNTService.bat** and **StartNTService.bat**.

Similar to [this (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750108/sonar-qube-installation-on-windows-server-2012) post, it says

```
wrapper | Starting the SonarQube service...
wrapper | The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.
```

The error log file says:

```
The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.
Starting the SonarQube service...
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library 'wrapper.dll'.
          The file is located on the path at the following location but
          could not be loaded:
            C:\tools\sonarqube-5.2\bin\windows-x86-64\.\lib\wrapper.dll
          Please verify that the file is readable by the current user
          and that the file has not been corrupted in any way.
          One common cause of this problem is running a 32-bit version
          of the Wrapper with a 64-bit version of Java, or vica versa.
          This is a 32-bit JVM.
          Reported cause:
            C:\tools\sonarqube-5.2\bin\windows-x86-64\lib\wrapper.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
          System signals will not be handled correctly.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory is not writable: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory is not writable: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\
    at org.sonar.process.MinimumViableSystem.checkWritableDir(MinimumViableSystem.java:60)
    at org.sonar.process.MinimumViableSystem.checkWritableTempDir(MinimumViableSystem.java:52)
    at org.sonar.process.MinimumViableSystem.check(MinimumViableSystem.java:45)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.process.MinimumViableSystem.checkWritableDir(MinimumViableSystem.java:57)
    ... 9 more
<-- Wrapper Stopped
The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.
```

And I don't know why it fails.

- I ran the application as admin
- I have the 64 bit Windows and Java installed
- the wrapper.dll is right in its place

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

[This](http://qualilogy.com/en/migrate-sonarqube-tomcat-to-windows-service/) page descibes a solution to the problem that I can't use as the dropdown menu on right button click on the service is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Goto C:\Sonar\conf\wrapper.conf open via notepad++ change the wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/java 
to your java installation path

Answer (score 2):

I find the following in the log, so I followed the instruction found here to change an account have local admin right, and it works: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows

WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Temp directory is not writable: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no clue about this anymore. I solved the problem a day later.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add service account (which is configured as per this [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows)) to local administrator group of the machine running sonar qube service

Answer (score 1):

Open "\conf\wrapper.conf:" file
replace

> wrapper.java.command=java

with

> wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. My solution was to verify that the java x64 JDK was installed - and problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and it got resolved after following all the above points ie
a. Making sure the service is running on admin login
b. JDK is installed using an admin login

Comment: It looks like this answer is really a comment on another answer.

Answer (score 0):

My organization installed 32-bit Java which added C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath as the default Java path. I defined **JAVA_HOME** and added **%JAVA_HOME%\bin;** to the start of my classpath for SonarQube to use the 64-bit version of Java that I installed.

https://douglascayers.com/2015/05/30/how-to-set-custom-java-path-after-installing-jdk-8/